# How does cout << " \n"[i == n - 1]; work?

Tags: c++

I didn't get how `[i == n-1]` works in this scenario

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << a[i] << " \n"[i == n - 1];
}
```

Comment: someone tried to be super clever

Comment: Hint: `false` is zero, `true` is one.

Comment: you can do a lot of tricky (and unnecessary) things with arrays. To top their attempt on obfuscation, reply with `std::cout << i[a] << (i == n - 1)[" \n"];`

Comment: Did they get any noticeable performance improvement out of this? Only their profiler knows for sure.

Comment: Branches can be very slow, so they might have been trying to avoid them, but I/O is far slower so it makes no difference. Might be useful if only constructing a string but there's a clearer way then, too.

Comment: Guys,but why does it print out `'e'`  if I print out `cout << "Hello" [i == 0]`. Isn't it supposed to print out `'H'` ?

Comment: It's right, think about it. `i == 0` is `1` only once, for the first iteration. If it's `(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)` then the output is `eHHHH`

Comment: `i == 0` is `true` (`1`) the first time, `"Hello"[1]` is `'e'`.

Comment: @JohnBayko Oh,yes I was careless :)

Comment: Maybe this would help: `(i == n - 1)[" \n"]`

Answer (score 4):

Expression `i == n-1` is a boolean expression that will evaluate to either `1` (True) or `0` (False).

`" \n"` is an array of 3 character values:

- `Space` (0x32)
- `\n`  (0x0D)
- `NULL` (0x00)

So the full expression will either evaluate to the `Space` or the `\n`, depending on if `i` is the last index of array `a`.

The complete for-loop with cout will print spaces up until `i` is at the end of the array, and then will finally print a `\n` after the last element.

It is clever, but confusing.   I would tell a programmer to find a better way.

I might prefer using a ternary operator (`? :`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << (i == n - 1) ? "\n" : " ";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string literal `" \n"` is of type `const char[3]` (one for the 0-terminator) and you can access elements of that array as usual:

```
assert(" \n"[0] == ' ');
assert(" \n"[1] == '\n');
```

The "index" `i == n-1` is `true` for all but the last iterations, which converts to `1` (while `false` becomes `0`). So the same could have been written more readable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ( i == n-1) {
        cout << a[i] << '\n';
    } else {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    } 
}
```